# Can I use facebooks game service for leaderboards and to send push notifications

Tags: facebook, mobile, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I'm making a mobile game in Unity.

I would like to have a leaderboard of high scores for a person and their facebook friends who have also played the game.

Also I would like for a push notification to be sent to a player if one of their friends beats their high score.

Would it be possible to achieve those two things using facebooks game service? Or would I need to write a server of my own to handle this?

(ps. its ok if for example the person who got the high score is asked 'would you like to tell derp, herp and glerp that you beat their high scores' and it works that way)

I'm asking here as facebooks game service doesnt seems to have anyone I can email for support or even a forum (Only a closed facebook group which I am still pending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook allows you to store 1 variable per user, so you could use that to store a score for each user and make a leaderboard based on that.

For push notifications there are two different kinds, one is actually called local notifications and you can make those for free without a server, but the user has to open the app for you to schedule them.
If you want to use the push notifications to react to a user beating a score you would either have to have your own server or use one of the many services out there. Some are even free like this one: https://onesignal.com/?gclid=CjwKEAjwm_K_BRDx5o-sxq6ouXASJAC7TsFLhiWC9-XUm1Sryg6zgEeQU49wLR7_H3WzzwOAnhX_exoCYIzw_wcB (you would have to read up on it though, I just searched around a bit.

You can also ask your user if they want to tell their friends on facebook that they beat their score, but before you can do that you will have to gain the permission of the users involved. Once you get in to the facebook documentation there is a guide on how to do this.

Hope it helps
Peter